# spring boot websocket+rabbitmq stomp with undertow ClassCastException

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket, undertow

when I use SocktJs to connect websocket,`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:8080/messages/019/1gso25hy/websocket; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer`,but I already exclude tomcat，why?

```
ext {
      propdepsPluginVersion = "0.0.7"
      springloadedVersion = "1.2.5.RELEASE"

      springDependencyManagementVersion = "0.5.4.RELEASE"
      springBootGradlePluginVersion = "1.3.2.RELEASE"
      springCloudStarterParentVersion = "Brixton.M5"
    }

dependencies {
  compile("tv.acfun.cloud.common:common:${commonVersion}")

  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude(module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
  }
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis")
  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
  compile("io.projectreactor:reactor-net")

  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix")
  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka")
  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp")
  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign")
}

2016-05-05 19:48:11.398 ERROR 6902 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] io.undertow.request                      : UT005023: Exception handling request to /messages/019/1gso25hy/websocket

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:8080/messages/019/1gso25hy/websocket; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202) ~[undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:8080/messages/019/1gso25hy/websocket; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer
  at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:135) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer
  at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.WebSocketTransportHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketTransportHandler.java:122) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:306) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:433) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:132) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer
  at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.getContainer(TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:85) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.getContainer(TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:48) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.getSupportedExtensions(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.java:88) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.doHandshake(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:274) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.WebSocketTransportHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketTransportHandler.java:118) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You can check it by looking inside dependence and make sure that tomcat is not there and try again.

Comment: looks like the JSR websocket implementation is there twice - so indeed, a dependency issue. Could you add the output of `gradle dependencies` to your question?

Comment: @BrianClozel  https://gist.github.com/Dreampie/dd9499160ad243d4ad740d82ef921fdc
`gradle dependencies` result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve it use config:

```
configurations {
  compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
```

This is not work,its so sad,I dont know why?

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
  exclude(module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}
```